# Como enviar dados do contato do form por e-mail com JS, ou HTML5 ou PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3, front-end

Olá, eu tenho feito o form com html5 e utilizando uma aparte do código em PHP para enviar o form deste jeito.

```
php -> { if (isset($_POST['BTEnviar'])) {

//Variaveis de POST, Alterar somente se necessário 
//====================================================
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone']; 
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
//====================================================

//REMETENTE --> ESTE EMAIL TEM QUE SER VALIDO DO DOMINIO
//==================================================== 
$email_remetente = "contato@meusite.com.br"; // deve ser uma conta de email do seu dominio 
//====================================================

//Configurações do email, ajustar conforme necessidade
//==================================================== 
$email_destinatario = "contato@meusite.com.br"; // pode ser qualquer email que receberá as mensagens
$email_reply = "$email"; 
$email_assunto = "Contato do Site meusite.com.br"; // Este será o assunto da mensagem
//====================================================

//Monta o Corpo da Mensagem
//====================================================
$email_conteudo = "Nome = $nome \n"; 
$email_conteudo .= "Email = $email \n";
$email_conteudo .= "Telefone = $telefone \n"; 
$email_conteudo .= "Mensagem = $mensagem \n"; 
//====================================================

//Seta os Headers (Alterar somente caso necessario) 
//==================================================== 
$email_headers = implode ( "\n",array ( "From: $email_remetente", "Reply-To: $email_reply", "Return-Path: $email_remetente","MIME-Version: 1.0","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" ) );
//====================================================

//Enviando o email 
//==================================================== 
if (mail ($email_destinatario, $email_assunto, nl2br($email_conteudo), $email_headers)){ 

                } 
        else{ 
                echo "</b>Falha no envio do E-Mail!</b>"; } 
//====================================================

-> HTML

<section id="contact" style="background-image: url(&quot;assets/img/contato3.jpg&quot;);background-color: #181818;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="text-uppercase section-heading">Fale conosco&nbsp;<i class="icon-speech"></i></h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;font-style: normal;"><strong>MANDE PELO FORMULÁRIO ABAIXO OU PARA O EMAIL:</strong><br><strong>meusite@gmail.com</strong></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="nome" placeholder="Seu Nome *" required="" autocomplete="on" inputmode="latin-name" minlength="3" autofocus=""><small class="form-text text-danger flex-grow-1 help-block lead"></small></div>
                            <div
                                class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Seu Email *" required="" autocomplete="on" inputmode="email" minlength="5"><small class="form-text text-danger help-block lead"></small></div>
                        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="tel" name="telefone" placeholder="Seu número *" required="" autocomplete="on" inputmode="tel" minlength="9"><small class="form-text text-danger help-block lead"></small></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="mensagem" placeholder="Conte mais sobre seu projeto *" required="" inputmode="latin" minlength="15"></textarea><small class="form-text text-danger help-block lead"></small></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                        <div id="success"></div><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit" name="BTEnviar" id="sendMessageButton">Enviar</button></div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Porém não está funcionando e o envio e quando eu aperto o botão de confirmar gostaria que aparecesse uma mensagem de confirmação de envio na tela com o nome do `input nome` algo do tipo: `[nome], sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Minhas recomendações são as seguintes. Se seu formulário é em HTML, show, você pode enviar via javascript para o php e o PHP envia por email.

Vamos lá... Recupere as informações do HTML e faça o post via javascript.

```
$.post({
                url: "handle.php", // o arquivo php que vai enviar email. 
                type: "POST", // HTTP verb
                data: {action: "enviar_email", nome: $('#nome').val(), email: $('#email').val(), telefone: $('#telefone').val(), mensagem: $('#mensagem').val()},

                success: function (response) {

                    if(response.trim() == '1'){
                      // se enviou certinho, voce ja pode mostrar a mensagem aqui mesmo
                       // crie sua variavel que vai exibir a mensagem ou utilize um alerta, vc que sabe
                            document.getElementById("mensagem_envio").innerHTML = "Email não foi enviado";

                    }else if (response.trim() == "0") {
                       // se falhou, mostra também - crie sua variavel que vai exibir a mensagem ou utilize um alerta, vc que sabe
                            document.getElementById("mensagem_envio").innerHTML = "Email não foi enviado";

                    }
                }
            });
```

OK ... javascript ta pronto.

Vamos para o php... MAS ANTES, recomendo usar o PHP MAILER.  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

em PHP fica assim.

```
    // esses includes são do MAILER. 
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPmailer/src/SMTP.php';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPmailer/src/Exception.php';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPmailer/src/OAuth.php';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    if ($_POST['action'] == 'enviar_email') {

    $mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

// aqui você retorna as informações do javascipt e monta a mensgame do email no seu formato, é que to com preguiça de montar
            $msg = 'nome:'.$_POST['nome'].' Email: ' .$_POST['email'].' Mensagem: '.$_POST['email'];


$assunto = 'assunto do email';


            $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
            $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
            $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = true;  // 
            $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com';  // SMTP utilizado
            $mail->Port = 587;          // A porta TCP que estiver habilitado
            $mail->Username = 'user@example.com'; // login
            $mail->Password = 'senha12344'; // senha
            $mail->SetFrom('not_replay@teste.com', 'não responder'); // o email que vai enviar
             $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($assunto);
            $mail->Body = utf8_decode($msg);

            $email_log = array();
            //EMAIL que vai enviar, se for array envia p varios senao só envia p um
            if(is_array($email)){
                foreach($email as $e){
                    $mail->AddAddress($e);

                }
            }else{
                $mail->AddAddress($email);

            }
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
                $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    } else {
                $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
                }
    }
```

sim, o código é grande e parece chato, mas acredite, é bem simples, basta praticar.

mas utilize o PHP Mailer, é bastante util, da até para enviar anexo.